# Change Rails application logging directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I'm new to Rails, but I have an existing Rails application for which I would like to change the default directory where it logs. What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: does it have to log to the other directory, or can you just symlink the directory to another location? In production deploys I have the `logs` directory symlinked to `deploy/shared/logs` this is the default for cap.

Comment: yeah, symlink could be an option, but is there a way to configure directory explicitly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there are different possibilities, on a production server, the log directory usually are sym-linked to a general log location, which i'd recommend if you want to write the logs to a directory outside your rails app. you can of course re-initialize the `Rails.logger` in your development.rb/production.rb/application.rb to any Logger / IOStream:

```
Rails.logger = Logger.new STDOUT #or File.open('somewhere/production.log', 'a'), i think it should even work with a stream of a tcp socket
```

Answer (score 9):

You can specify an explicit logger in your config;

```
my_logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new(path)
config.logger = my_logger
```

This will replace Rails.logger

Answer (score 0):

There are good details on how to configure loggers and what options are available in this [Rails Configuration Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html).

Note you can actually set up different loggers for active_record / action_controller / active_resource / etc, if you want to. This also includes details on how to set log_level via the config.